# open developer menu after install debug apk react-native

Tags: react-native, react-devtools

Currently, I'm working on a big tablet android like the advertisement board.
I'm trying to use react-native for it and the only port that they have is USB. I'm trying to open the developer menu but have no idea how. I am installing the apps by sending the debug apk using the drive.

Things that I try:-

1. shake the big tab, might be they do not have the sensor for it
2. use USB male to male did not detect the USB as adb or anything.

any idea how to open this one? it's pretty hard to not see the console.

Tab Information:
Model number
Quad-Core R18 ads

Android version
android 6.0.1

firmware version
ads_v1.0

kernel version
3.10.65
xiao@yh-Series2 #225

Comment: use adb over tcp instead of usb, After that you can see the logs on your shell or even push and install application.

Comment: @RachitSolanki can you describe more on the process? I never hear about adb over tcp.. so if im using adb tcpip <>, how do i know which devices should i connect ? 

adb tcpip 192.168.0.189.. is this the correct way ? and I need to do this after i install my debug apk on the devices right ?

Comment: adb connect 192.168.0.189:5555 is use to connect if it did not work then please follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp

Comment: the one that I read, I still need to use usb to set the port adb tcpip right ?

Comment: not necessary if your device is already configure and if not then you need to set them to property file this you can add via downloading any shell application to android

Comment: alright.. thanks @RachitSolanki!, got it.. i got connection refused but once i install adb wifi from the device, it's working